# Strange import error in Emscripten cross-compiled CPython

Tags: python, cpython, emscripten

I am porting CPython to Emscripten, and it builds successfully. However, when I try to run the python.asm.js through Node.js, I get a very strange error inside the `Py_InitializeEx(0)` call:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 44, in <module>
    from posix import *
TypeError: 'NotImplementedType' object does not support indexing
```

The error is generated from `PySequence_GetItem` in `Objects/abstract.c`, but I don't understand how the execution gets there. If I do `import posix` before the line that causes the error, the `import posix` statement finish successfully, and I can call functions in the posix module. Thus, the error is related to `from <module> import *` line. How is `PySequence_GetItem` related to `from <module> import *` statement, and what could be the reasons for the error?

If you want to reproduce the problem, I [released the code on GitHub](https://github.com/PeachPy/EmCPython)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While investigating what is going wrong, I switched off the optimization (compiled and linked with `-O0`). The resulting JS executable also failed, but with a different error:

```
Invalid function pointer '495' called with signature 'iii'. Perhaps this is
an invalid value (e.g. caused by calling a virtual method on a NULL pointer)?
Or calling a function with an incorrect type, which will fail? (it is worth
building your source files with -Werror (warnings are errors), as warnings can
indicate undefined behavior which can cause this)
This pointer might make sense in another type signature:
  ii: _dict_keys  iiii: 0  i: undefined  iiiii: 0  viii: 0  vii: 0  vi: 0  v: 0
495
495
```

I looked through Emscripten's [settings.js](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js) for options related to function pointers, and found `EMULATE_FUNCTION_POINTER_CASTS` which fixed the problem.